# Is deleting my entire home folder contents like resetting everything to where it was during install?

Tags: bash, home-directory, .profile

Or does Kubuntus install process generates something in there that is not generated like it is now after I deleted everything.

Sidequestion that led me to this is. Does 13.04 don't have the /home/user/bin automatically added to the path like it was before? Because I copied my scripts there and they are not working.

There is no .profile like it was before, because I deleted everything or because there simply is non in 13.04? If it is there normally where it comes from, how do I reset my home to defaults then?

Maybe this is generated during the creation of a user? Any other things that might be missing now?

Comment: To closevoters: This IS a real, answerable question.

Answer (score 3):

This may not be the answer you're looking for, but I would say no. There are other folders like 'bin', 'usr', 'etc', etc. that have most likely been modified since your installation. So, unless you just installed and haven't downloaded any apps or modified anything, simply deleting the 'home' folder would not turn it into a clean slate.

Comment: Well since all I changed was the fstab and apache virtual hosts I more or less have the default settings everywhere else, so this is not what I meant.

Answer (score 2):

> Is deleting my entire home folder contents like resetting everything to where it was during install?

**No:** some files are created when install or create a new user if you delete all your files you wont get the default files back.  Also changes do not only happen in your home directory.  This is especially true if you have installed or removed any software.

> Doesn't 13.04  have the /home/user/bin automatically added to the path like it was before?

This is set in your `.profile` file at least in 12.10 and older.  I would expect this to be true in 13.04 too.  But since its not officially released yet I have not upgraded my test machine.  If you have deleted all your home directory you will have deleted this file so it won't happen any more.

If you want to get back as it was with a fresh install I would just reinstall.

An alternative would be to create a new user but make sure they are an **administrator** or they won't be able to use `sudo`.

Answer (score 0):

just an esample:
the file .bashrc will not be "autoregenerate"
if you delete it, you will lose the autocomplete function in bash by tab button.

Sidequestion: are you script exe permission? (chmod a+x) if you copy the file via formatted fat32 key you lose this metadata.

Yes, the simplest way to reset the default option is creating a new user.

Please, don't be wondering if you delete all .config and something unwanted happen...
Ubuntu isn't black magik! :)

ps if you push "ctrl h" being in your home via graphic interface (not via bash), you will hide/show the .config file (if you didn't delete them...)

Bye

Comment: Your right I don't have lost the tab option and no nothing bad happens then you delete all files in .config. All the default apps do a pretty good job recreating config with default values, I do it all the time to reset programs. This is just the first time I did this to redically for the entire home without backing up. Guess I create a new user then, I guessed this myself already though.

Comment: And no nothing happens when I push CTRL+H in Dolphin but I for sure know how to display hidden files, I have a Icon for that setup in Dolphin what made me look that noob?

Answer (score 0):

As already explained, you will lose all the settings related to yourself. AFAIK, the bin thing is included in `.profile` but once you delete it you will be using the system one found in `/etc/profile`. Also, I think ubuntu uses setting files from `/etc/skel` when creating a user. You can copy `.bashrc` and `.profile` from this folder to your home.

Answer (score 0):

K, creating a new user in the KDE user management created exactly 3 files

1. .bashrc
2. .profile
3. .bash_logout

So more and more believe that deleting all files except this 3 is almost exactly the same as if you would reinstall and login to the desktop the first time. I copy this files over, set permissions right and everything should be fine.

This following of course expect that there is nothing in there that is important and not backed up:
I don't thing @gio900's concern that something bad would happen. Yes Ubuntu lacks black magic but thats fine because as I see it does not need anything special to do here. KDE/GNOME/WHATEVER APP will just create configs with defaults if nothing is there. The default "Desktop, Music, Documents ..." folders are also created as they where by default.

I may log into this newly created user at a later time and check if something else is generated during login that not generated for my current user after I deleted everything but I highly doubt that this will be the case. Else I will edit this.

Comment: When you create a user, files are copied from `/etc/skel`. A lot of programs create files in your home directory on first run, so I would expect there to be more files after you log in.